# Parallelize HTTP requests with Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using pyspark to do some data transformation: like the following :

```
df_systems_tree_users = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc") \
    .option("dbtable",
            "(select ID as SYSTEMUID,M_EXTERNAL_ID,metric,DATATRANSMISSIONFREQUENCY,MODEL,BRAND,BUILDING FROM SYSTEM  INNER JOIN SENSOR ON SYSTEM.ID=SENSOR.SYSTEMID WHERE LPWANOPERATOR='Objenious' AND M_EXTERNAL_ID!='None' )") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:phoenix:master1:2181:/hbase-unsecure") \
    .option("driver", "org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver") \
    .load()
objRDD = df_systems_tree_users.rdd.map(lambda x: getStatesAndUplink(x))
```

getStatesAndUplink method uses requests python library to execute an http get request to an external api.

I run this spark job on 4 executors with 4 cores each , but it takes alot of time to run 30 minutes .

My question is how to optimize my code to parallelize in a efficient way my http requests ?

Comment: What's in your getStatesAndUplink(x) function exactly? Sticking with dataframes and using a UDF might be faster.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases), you must specify 4 arguments:

- `partitionColumn`,
- `lowerBound`,
- `upperBound`,
- `numPartitions`

Only with those options Spark will parallelize reading - in other cases, it will be done in one thread.

Edit: There exist [Phoenix Spark plugin](https://phoenix.apache.org/phoenix_spark.html). It will parallelize reading without specifying those 4 arguments.

Edit 2: Method `getStatesAndUplink` may be throttling external service if the data is unbalanced. It may just "stuck" on processing on one node